# what's the difference between "send along" and "send"?

Tags: difference

When I read the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/conditional-view-processing/):

> When the client next requests the same resource, it might **send along** a header such as either `If-modified-since` or `If-unmodified-since`, containing the date of the last modification time it was sent.

I saw there are `send along` here, I know its meaning. but you know, we can use `send` directly, why there is more – an `along` here?

What's the difference between `send along` and `send`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meaning of *along* is "additionally" or "extra" in the sense of delivering something else other than what was expected.

*Along* is used because not only is the requested resource being sent (that's implied in the sentence), but also a header.  If *along* did not appear in the sentence, it could mean the header was sent *instead* of the resource.

*Send X along* where X is a person and there is nothing specified for *along* can mean "to dismiss," but this is not what is meant here.